Modifying theme and wishlist
i have 2 issue with a theme, if possible can someone point me to a right direction.
First issue i have is the SOLD button on the product showing as SOLD, and i wanted to change it to SOLD OUT, i dug in a code and couldnt find it how to change it, same in the settings menu.
Another issue is when i hover the mouse over the bookmark icon (wishlist) instead of it changing pictures from hollow one to a filled one, it just overlaps over the other. If possible please help, Here is the website and image
Reached out to author but no reply.
Thank you

This is really specific to whatever theme you're using and not just a universal WP thing that someone can easily answer.  You're better off reaching out to the theme developers to see if they have any documentation.

It looks okay to me. This might be more of a CSS or JavaScript type question.
